# How to apply margin-top to <small> tag?

Tags: html, css, tags

I want to set `margin-top` to `<small>` tag. In other word I how can I increase the space of `<small>` tag with the upper element?

**Note:** I can increase the space using `line-height`, But I just want to set space from the top, not both top and bottom.

```css
small{
    margin-top: 100px;
    color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div>It is a test<div>
<small>this need to some margin-top</small>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [**Box Model - 8.3 Margin properties**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties)
>
> Margin properties specify the width of the margin area of a box. The 'margin' shorthand property sets the margin for all four sides while the other margin properties only set their respective side. These properties apply to all elements, but vertical margins will **not have any effect on non-replaced inline elements**.

A `small` tag is `inline` by default. As stated by the spec above, vertical margins do not apply to strictly `inline` level elements.

You could change the `display` to `inline-block`, and it would work as expected:

```css
small {
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>It is a test<div>
<small>this need to some margin-top</small>
```

Comment: Very well, Thanks, +1.

Comment: Sorry for asking again. Can you please take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8m03ny1z/) and tell me how should I prevent of going out `<small>` from `<div>`?

Comment: @Shafizadeh Either add `overflow: hidden` to the parent element to hide it [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/huqsrg6o/). Or use `width: calc(100% - 20px)` [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/ospmyrkp/). Or do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zer9ey3m/).